# Can a progressive policy be solely funded by a regressive or even proportional tax?

Tags: taxation

Under what criteria a regressive or proportional tax can be used to fully fund a welfare program or policy that it's progressive (i.e., one that benefits lower-income people more) in nature? Are there any examples worldwide?

Comment: Are you asking if there are any regressive/proportional taxes that result in higher tax revenue than any welfare programs? This could be decided by looking at the annual budgets of different countries.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I collect \$1 from everyone and give it out to the poor, then it's a progressive policy (helping the poor) funded by a proportional tax?

Comment: @Art - I think a \$1 poll tax would usually be seen as regressive as not being proportional to some measure of being rich/poor such as wealth, income or expenditure

Comment: A well-designed sales tax is proportional to expenditure, i.e. to standard of living.  If used to fund education (as in some US states) so children across the rich/poor spectrum all get the same benefits, then it can be seen as progressive.

Comment: Oh new knowledge. I've always thought that progressive tax is when the rich pay more than the poor. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Henry, what about a regressive tax?